# How to Build ODB on Mac OS X 10.11

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, odb

I am trying to build ODB on El Capitan. I am confused about the versions of xcode as they pertain to clang.

Looking at [ODB's 2.4.0 announcement](http://www.codesynthesis.com/pipermail/odb-announcements/2015/000041.html) shows the following information:

```
Platform     Compiler Version  C++ Std     Arch       Qt Boost Databases
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mac OS X      Clang   3.5      C++11     x86 32/64    -    -   All ex MS SQL
```

Sounds simple enough, so I need Clang 3.5!

On my Mac, I run the following

```
$ g++ -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

And now I am confused, since `clang-602.0.53` seems to be completely different from clang 3.5.

Where can I go to get Clang 3.5 and use it to build ODB?